# Arduino undefined reference to `operator

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-errors, arduino, arduino-ide

I am working on one project where I am using arduino. I am running Fedora 24 and Arduino IDE 1.6.4. I have wanted to continue in my work yesterday but I could not. New compilation error appeared. Last time everything was working OK. A have also tried some other older working sketches, they display the same error now.

```
Arduino: 1.6.4 (Linux), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328"

Build options changed, rebuilding all
arduino.cpp.o: In function `setup':
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h:111: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h:111: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

I remember that I was using "dnf update" before and it updated also kernel. I have already tried to reinstall arduino IDE with removing the .arduino15 directory and reinstall all of my libraries. Nothing helps. How can I fix ths compiling error?

Comment: What do you think have your host kernel to do with a linker error from your arduino code?

Comment: You should take care that your c++-lib is linked with your code. But I can't tell you why your ide do not link with it. I prefer writing my own Makefiles and see what I do. Having some kind of black box which do everything more or less automatic can result in such problems... If you can show us the underlying Makefile, we can give you some advice. But only the error message is not enough to get catch problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already solved my problem. I have tried different things but this worked:

1. uninstall Arduino IDE thru terminal
2. delete `.arduino15` folder
3. search for any directory called `arduino` and remove it with `sudo rm -r`
4. install the lastest Arduino IDE version directly from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software